# qmv from renameutils doesn't support non-ASCII characters? $EDITOR shows bytes instead of Unicode chars

Tags: rename

```bash
export $EDITOR=nvim
mkdir -p /tmp/qmv
cd /tmp/qmv
touch ‍
qmv -f do *
```

In Neovim (and nano too) it shows this:

```
\360\237\221\250\342\200\215\360\237\222\273
```

instead of this:

```
‍
```

Is this a bug? Should I contact the author directly (because I don't think there is any issue tracker available)?

Comment: There *is* a bug tracker, http://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?group=renameutils , but it seems rather unwatched.

Comment: I don't want to paint a bad picture, but `renameutils` seems to be software that the author considered "beta" and hasn't touched in 12 years – "it's *dead*, Jim", to quote a sci-fi series.

Comment: I guess it is time to make my own renamer that uses `$EDITOR`. I wasn't able to find anything that just works.

Comment: honestly sounds like 10 lines of zsh… Beware that all this can go **horribly** wrong when there's file with line breaks in their name, if you're just using line breaks as separators.

Comment: Yes, [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736906/qmv-from-renameutils-doesnt-support-non-ascii-characters-editor-shows-bytes-i#comment1399414_736906) was exactly my though when the idea of my renamer came to my mind. But if we are talking only about Unicode characters and not the special ones (# < 32), then it will be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a bug. And not the only one:
http://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?group=renameutils

But as Marcus Müller [said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736906/qmv-from-renameutils-doesnt-support-non-ascii-characters-editor-shows-bytes-i#comment1399407_736906), it is probably won't be fixed (the oldest bug is 17 years old).